# Selenium webdriver Server Error (500) error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm logging in to a site using Selenium. After logging in I get a Server Error (500) error when I want to go to another link through the same site.

asd.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")


browser.get('site-login-url')

username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")

username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")

browser.find_element_by_id("btn-login").click()

time.sleep(3)

browser.get('site-login-url/validation/?asd=asd&dsa=dsa')
```

Login process is work fine. But second get url is not working. Trying to access the second url gives Server Error (500) error. How can i fix this.

Comment: Presumably, after you `.click()` after entering credentials, the browser should already be moving to/past the validation page on its own. Why do you need to call the second URL manually?

Comment: The main work I want to do is in the second url. Since I didn't set "next=?" when I was logged in, I had to login first. Then I will go to the second url and perform the operation. @G.Anderson

Comment: One way to test whether this is a selenium problem, or normal browser behavior (which I suspect is the case): Do the same steps manually. If you go to the first url in a fresh browser page, enter your login credentials, then in the same windows paste in the second URL and hit enter, do you get the same error?

Comment: You're right. I did the steps you said by hand, and I came across the same error again. But when I go to the url manually, it opens without error. Why is this caused by? @G.Anderson

Comment: The [(500) internal server error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) is a generic error for web servers. It's likely this is a server-side issue where you're trying to manually access a URL that can only be generated by the server, not accessed directly

Comment: Perhaps the server is not set up to accept the url directly even after login? You'll need to find a reliable way to navigate back to the second url without errors and then program your `selenium` to follow the same steps.

Comment: If you are logging in without using selenium, what does the flow look like? i.e.- "Go to URL>enter credentials>click login button>?" Rather than accessing a second page, can you navigate the resulting page by clicking rather than going to the new URL?

Comment: Flow to access the site; Go to url, enter information, press login. This flow is used with both manual and selenium. Maybe I'm going to have to move clicking with selenium as you said. I'm gonna try this idea. @G.Anderson

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a server error. I'm gonna try the idea you said. @Idlehands